# Serializing from an object into an XML node

Tags: c#, web-services

I have 2 web services. One web service takes in an object of type A. When using the "Add Service Reference" in Visual Studio, it creates a class called `AType`.

My second web service's input method (called x(...)) actually takes in a parameter of type A but for some reason the WSDL is incorrect and declares it as ##any.

```
<any namespace="##any" processContents="lax" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1">
```

This means that in my code, I would have to create an XmlElement from an XmlDocument:

```
private static XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
XmlElement e = doc.CreateElement("some-name", "some-uri");
```

Is there a way I can convert AType into an XmlElement? Do I have to go back to string first?

As an alternative I am thinking of merging my two web service WSDL files...

Comment: Do you mean serialize an object into an XML node?

Comment: Yes. Sorry about the wrong terminology

Comment: WSDL is correct, just in way Microsoft sees .NET WebServices WSDL, <any> is legal schema type used, AType is a generated type, XmlElement is a part of XmlDocument. You do not need to convert generated type to XmlDocument, i do not see any practical scenario for that, especially you do not provide code, sample, or details why you need such strange thing

Comment: That does not answer my question :-) I know the WSDL is OK (it could have been better typed but that's another question)

Comment: @DavidBrossard If you give a working scenario, I can help you, I'm not going to gess what are you thinking of, describe it please

Answer (score 0):

I finally found that the following code does exactly what I am looking for:

```
    public static XmlElement Serialize(MyObject someClassInstance)
    {            
        XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(MyObject));
        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();

        XPathNavigator nav = doc.CreateNavigator();
        XmlWriter writer = nav.AppendChild();
        serializer.Serialize(writer, someClassInstance);
        writer.WriteEndDocument();
        writer.Flush();
        writer.Close();
        return doc.DocumentElement;
    }
```